# Converting factors to numeric but getting NAs

Tags: r

I am converting factors to numbers and have tried both solutions previously posted:

```
   as.numeric(as.character(factor))  
   as.numeric(levels(factor))
```

In both cases: I get lots of NA's and a warning message, NAs introduced by coercion.  When I typed levels(factor), I do get many percentages (i.e. these are interest rates).

Is there any way I can convert these interest rates, whose class is factor, into numeric?

Thanks,

Shelley

Comment: In order to answer with accuracy, we need to see your data and exactly what you're tried. However, I'm assuming you have factor levels such as "14" and "3.2%", and when you try to convert the levels to numbers, you get 14 and NA--right? You need to remove the "%". E.g.: `as.integer(gsub("\\D", "", "14%"))`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please post some code, ideally a reproducible example with data? See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/946850 for this.

Answer (score 3):

A "number" with percentage symbol is not considered as a numeric or integer in R, so you need to remove this symbol in every number first using for example `gsub` before doing the coercion.

```
perc <- factor(c("10%", "21.6%", "15%"))

as.numeric(as.character(perc))
[1] NA NA NA
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion 


as.numeric(gsub("\\%", "", perc))
[1] 10.0 21.6 15.0
```